# use javascript xml xslt to set click event on last li

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

this is my xslt file:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[2]]" 
                           mode="item" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with this xslt i have create HTML tag `ul li`
here is my xml file:-

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="b.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
  <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
      <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
        <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
          <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
        </child_6>
      </child_3>
      <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
        <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
      </child_4>
      <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
        <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
      </child_5>
    </child_2>
</child_1>
</root>
```

now i want to set click event on li if li have child then its text print on div tag.
i have one javascript function also.

```
$('li:not(:has(*))').click(function(){
   $('#result').text($(this).text());
});
```

but how can i apply i dont know this.
a little bit help i need . some buddy help me out of this.
thanks.

Comment: I'm getting confused about again nearly the same question from different user [e.g](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16213034/2115381), or is "jack lanza" the same gui than "Jack Php"?

Comment: "George of all trades" is right your hmtl list seems to be wrong. But also the example from "George of all trades"looks still wrong to me. Your problem is also not really clear. You do not know how to execute the piece of javascirpt?

Answer (score 0):

Your current xsl gives the following output:

```
<ul>
   <li>Activities</li>
   <ul>
      <li>Physical1</li>
      <ul>
         <li>Cricket</li>
         <ul>
            <li>One Day</li>
         </ul>
      </ul>
      <li>Test1</li>
      <ul>
         <li>Test At Abc</li>
      </ul>
      <li>Test2</li>
      <ul>
         <li>Test At Xyz</li>
      </ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Really the the nested ul are themselves list items so should be inside li tags, and there are one or two other problems which fixed gives:

```
<ul>
   <li>Activities</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Physical1</li>
         <li>
            <ul>
               <li>Cricket</li>
            </ul>
         <li>One Day</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Test1</li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Test At Abc</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Test2</li>
      <ul>
         <li>Test At Xyz</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

It is not entirely clear what you are after, please edit the question to show the desired output, I can then advise on the xsl you need. As for including the script, the following will work - use either the inline or external link as required:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <xsl:call-template name="HeaderTemplate" />
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="HeaderTemplate">

    <head>
    <script>
        function MyFunction()
            {

            }
    </script>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    </head>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```