# click event on li its not work perfect

Tags: javascript, xml, function, xslt

this is my xml file:-

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="b.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
  <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
      <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
        <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
          <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
        </child_6>
      </child_3>
      <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
        <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
      </child_4>
      <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
        <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
      </child_5>
    </child_2>
</child_1>
</root>
```

this is my xslt code:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="item">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::node()/child::*">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li onclick="final()">
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[*]"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/*/*">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1] | node()[current()/ancestor::*[3]]" mode="item"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

here i try to get Activities from xml file
and if a last li  then set there one function as a attribute type like :-

```
<li onclick ="final()">One Day</li>
```

it only set last li which no have child...
now i am create one javascript file for getting xslt and html output.:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script>
    function final(){
        $('li:not(:has(*))').click(function(){
        alert('click');
        $('#result').text($(this).text());
        });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var xml = loadXMLDoc("final.xml");
        var xsl = loadXMLDoc("b.xsl");



        function loadXMLDocOther(location) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", location, false);
            xhttp.send("");
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

        function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return loadXMLDocActiveX(dname);
            }
            else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return loadXMLDocOther(dname);
            }
        }        
        function transformOther(xml, xsl, target, selected) {
            var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

            if (selected) {
                xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "selected", selected);
            }

            var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
            target.innerHTML = "";
            target.appendChild(resultDocument);
        }

        function displayResult() {
            var targetElement = document.getElementById("load");

            // code for IE
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                transformActiveX(xml, xsl, targetElement);
            }
            // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else if (document.implementation && 
                     document.implementation.createDocument) {
                transformOther(xml, xsl, targetElement);
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
    <div id="load">
    </div>
    <div id="result">result</div>
</body>
```

this is my javascript code to click on last li its value append in `<div id="result">`

```
<script>
        function final(){
            $('li:not(:has(*))').click(function(){
            alert('click');
            $('#result').text($(this).text());
            });
            }
        </script>
```

now problem is i am click on last li its work but its work something like for loop. i got this problem when i try to one alert.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to know what you are trying to.  Therefor here first an explanation what you are doing. You generate a html fragment like this (via xlst):

```
<ul>
    <li>Physical1<ul>
        <li>Cricket<ul>
            <li onclick="final()">One Day</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There is one onlclick handlder (`onclick="final()`) at the li element without children.

```
function final(){
        $('li:not(:has(*))').click(function(){
        alert('click');
        $('#result').text($(this).text());
        });
        }
```

Firs click on "One Day" item calls final(). The final function than sets new onclick handler to all  li elements with not children.
**Which is the same and only element which has already an final as onclick hanlder**
Because of event propagation the next click calls the new hanlder and afterward final. Which installs  again a new onclick handler. Now wee have already three handler on the element. And each click add one more. To stop this can you try to use `event.stopPropagation();` or to remove the event handler `attr('onclick', '').off('click');`

```
function final() {
    var lis = $('li:not(:has(*))');
    lis.attr('onclick', '').off('click');
        $('li:not(:has(*))').click(function(event) {
              $('#result').text($(this).text());
        });
    }
```

But I more suspect that the selector is wrong `$('li:not(:has(*))')`.
Some more comments:
 - It would not make lot sense to set event handler to your parent `<li>` elements either. Because the li elements include each other (**what is correct!**) clicking on an child will also trigger the handler of the parent elements.
 - Therefore (perhaps) you should add elements around the content (text) of the li elements.
(`<li><span>Physical1</span><ul><li>...`)
 - Than you can add the onclick handler the span elements.
 - If only the "final" elements should trigger an event, you do not need to set any new click functions.

```
function final(){
        alert('click');
        $('#result').text($(this).text());
        }
```

Comment: @Jack Php: Do you have some more information what you are indent?